# How to fix grayed out import module in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, import, project

I am trying to merge a few projects into one and therefore have to import either the projects or the modules. When i try "import project..." however, Android Studio will just open another instance of itself, not making any changes to the project. When i try import module, it will gray out the "Finish" button as soon as a module is checked for importing. If none is checked, it will let me continue... and do nothing as expected.

I am using Ubuntu and Android Studio Arctic Fox (newest version, freshly updated)

I already reinstalled and tried to fiddle around with project settings without any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a solution, but i found a workaround. It is possible to merge projects manually by copying the desired module folder "as is" into the new project folder and then copy the file ".idea/modules/modulename.iml" from the old project to the new one. Then one has to add "include ':modulename'" to the settings.gradle and add the path to the .iml file to .idea/modules.xml according to the format the other modules are saved in. Manually invoking gradle synch will update the project structure or show errors, if some were made.

Comment: I'm disappointed to say that this is still an issue it seems

Comment: Yep, it still is. . .